# apache-2.4.57 -- solaris installation giving error

Tags: apache2.4

Making install in support
ld: fatal: relocation error: R_SPARC_TLS_LE_HIX22: file server/.libs/libmain.a(util.o): symbol : bad symbol type SECT: symbol type must be TLS
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `httpd' Current working directory /var/tmp/httpd-2.4.57-Solaris/BUILD/httpd-2.4.57 *** Error code 1 The following command caused the error: otarget=`echo install-recursive|sed s/-recursive//`; \ list='  srclib os server modules support'; \ for i in $list; do \ if test -d "$i"; then \ target="$otarget"; \ echo "Making $target in $i"; \ if test "$i" = "."; then \ made_local=yes; \ target="local-$target"; \ fi; \ (cd $i && /usr/ccs/bin/make $target) || exit 1; \ fi; \ done; \ if test "$otarget" = "all" && test -z 'httpd shared-build '; then \ made_local=yes; \ fi; \ if test "$made_local" != "yes"; then \ /usr/ccs/bin/make "local-$otarget" || exit 1; \ fi make: Fatal error: Command failed for target` install-recursive'
Exiting Build_Component with errors
Error Compiling httpd on Solaris
exit status was 1

I'm trying to build apache-2.4.57 on Solaris. I wanted it go forward and build kit without any error.